# Duplicates in lazy loaded static collection

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, dictionary, thread-safety

In our asp.net application, we are lazy loading few frequently used data(e.g Countries) from db to static dictionary. The issue is, occasionally the dictionary has two copies of each country.

The main part of VB code is below.

```
Private Shared MyCountries As Dictionary(Of String, Country)

Shared Function Countries() As Dictionary(Of String, Country)

    If IsNothing(MyCountries) Then
        MyCountries = (From o In (New MyAppDBContext()).Countries Order By o.CountryCode Ascending).ToDictionary(Function(value As Country) value.CountryCode)
    End If

    Return MyCountries

End Function
```

I understand there is a chance for multiple threads to update the dictionary at the same time. But I thought, that would only assign the static variable with a new dictionary object and there will be no duplicates.

Is my understanding right or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your change your `Dictionary` to be a `ConcurrentDictionary`, this will be thread safe. i.e. two threads can add or remove items from the dictionary at the same time:

```
Public Shared Countries As Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Country)
```

Well, by definition a dictionary cannot have duplicate keys, **but** what happens when two threads add the same value at exactly the same time. Answer: undefined - either:

- *one* will throw an exception or
- *both* keys will be added.

`ConcurrentDictionary` adds a lock around the adding so only one thread can do this at a time

Comment: just curious, so the dictionary can have duplicate values in a non-thread safe case like mine? shouldn't it error out or update an existing key instead of adding a duplicate item?